# How can i animate a div background color without affecting the text inside the div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to animate a `div`'s `background-color` and set `opacity:0` while also keeping text inside the `div` visible.

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #block {
        background-color:#FF7F7F;
        display:none;
        padding:2px;
    }
</style>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#animate').click(function() {
            $('#block').show('slow');
            $('#block').animate({
                opacity: 0.00
            });         
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="block">
    <p id="text">
        hello there
    </p>
</div>
<a href="#" id="animate">Animate</a>
```

The problem is that I just need the background transparent and the text to stay visible. Like when you check for post in Facebook, the background color is animating to be transparent and the text stays visible to readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having separate "background div" positioned under the text div. use relative positioning to do that. then you have all the freedom to animate the background div as you wish keeping text intact

Comment: i assume i will use z-index in css to accomplish this , correct ?

Comment: yes, use z-index to position the overlay or underlay as necessary

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opacity, you need to change the background colour using rgba or hsla. Neither are supported in old IEs.

Instead, you could absolutely position a div behind the text, then animate opacity of that, leaving the text in a different div on top with a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

check this out http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="block">
</div>
<p id="text">
hello there
</p>
</div>
<a href="#" id="animate">Animate</a>
```